# input data of a Mapreduce program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to write a MapReduce code. My code has three parts: Data preparation, MapReduce and data post processing. The output of data preparation phase can be a 2D array or list.  My question is that how should I feed the mapper with the output of the first phase? Should I export it into txt file and import it again? if so, how should I provide the file location? using url? and if not, can I directly feed mapper with a list or array? I tried to find a similar case online, but I could not find anything.

Comment: Why do you want to use mapreduce is there any specific reason? Are you dealing with huge data set because mapreduce works best when it deals with huge dataset?

Comment: @Binary01: Yes, you are right! I'm dealing with a huge amount of matrix computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first job generates a file. The job script should copy the file into HDFS using

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /your/local/folder /your/folder/in/hdfs
```

Use `/your/folder/in/hdfs` as input folder for the MapReduce job. If your map reduce is a java based one, you can call your map reduce job as

```
hadoop jar yourCode.jar yourDriverClass \
-files any_file_that_you_want_to_be_available_with_job.txt \
-libjars supporting_librarys_if_any.jar \
folder_containing_input_file \
folder_to_expect_output_files
```

*Please note that above command line assumes that your driver class is using arg[0] as input folder and arg[1] as output folder*

In this case `folder_containing_input_file` = `/your/folder/in/hdfs`

So to answer your questions

- Should I export it into txt file and import it again?

  - yes
- if so, how should I provide the file location?

  - detailed above
- using url?

  - Using URL is an option but the above one is the easiest for your situation
- if not, can I directly feed mapper with a list or array?

  - please elaborate what is "direct". If you want all the mappers to be able to see the same file then your option will be to use `-files` option in command line. Using `-files` makes the file act like a cache file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok then you can write the output of first step into a file as comma seperated string i.e your list .So your every list will be a new line in the file and then move the file from you local file system to hdfs. Then you can use the hdfs file as input to the map reduce job to do the necessary. Or is it that you get only one list at a time as output of first job? In order to copy files from local file system to hdfs you can use the java API for hdfs file system. [Check this link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#copyFromLocalFile%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29)

Now if the output of your first job is just one 2D list then I think that is not suitable input for the map reduce job as it works best on bulk data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How should I move my file from local to HDFS inside my code? I heard we can do using url but I do not know how.

Comment: Regarding your question, I should say the output of the first job is just one 2D list.